# $A^2$ is bounded $\implies$ $A$ is bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of $k \times k$ real matrices. Assume $A_n^2$ is bounded w.r.t some norm. Is $A_n$ also bounded?

I was able to show this is true if $A_n$ are symmetric matrices (using SVD).

Is it true in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, try $A_n = \pmatrix{0 & n\cr 0 & 0\cr}$.